# Disable Text Field Autofocus in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, user-interface, modal-dialog

Is there a way in Javascript to forcibly disable text field autofocus on page load?

I know of the focus() method, but not how to disable it. My actual problem is that autofocusing in a modal window forces the window to appear with the scrollbar halfway down already and scrolled to the first input field, whereas I would like to disable this entirely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `.blur()` ,

```
var elelist = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < elelist.length; i++){
    elelist[i].blur();
}
```

If you want to disable focus on all the textfields,

```
var elelist = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < elelist.length; i++){
    elelist[i].addEventListener("focus", function(){
        this.blur();
    });
}
```

Comment: or blur by id in my case `document.getElementById("search").blur();`

Answer (score 5):

You can use in jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('input').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There's something in the Javascript code you're using that's setting the focus to the field, this is not an automatic behavior.  Just find that and disable it.

Answer (score 1):

You could force focus on an object higher in the page on load.